# SQL select the record whose HIGHEST timestamp is the LOWEST

Tags: sql, postgresql, max, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a database that contains duplicated names and timestamps
I want to retrieve the record whose timestamp is the lowest grouped by the name.

```
table : people
+------------+-------------+
|  Name      |  Timestamp  |
+------------+-------------+
|   name1    |   0         |
|   name1    |   5         |
|   name2    |   2         |
|   name3    |   3         |
|   name2    |   1         |
+--------------------------+
```

With a database in this state the query should return "name2, 2" since the highest value for name2 is the lowest of the max value of all groups.

I've been thinking a lot about this since I know I've done similar queries but my SQL skills are too rusty.

Thanks to anyone that takes the time to help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you  want the name whose greatest timestamp is the lowest: if so, you can use aggregation and limit:

```
select name
from people
group by name
order by max(timestamp)
limit 1
```

If you want to allow possible ties:

```
select name
from (
    select name, rank() over(order by max(timestamp)) rn
    from people
    group by name
) t
where rn = 1
```

On the other hand, if you want the entire record, I would recommend `distinct on` in Postgres:

```
select *
from (
    select distinct on (name) *
    from people
    order by name, timestamp desc
) t
order by timestamp
limit 1
```

Comment: Looks like aggregation and limit is the way to go, I'm working on it but you've definately helped a lot, thank you so much

Comment: still dont know how to extract the whole record without using another query

Comment: @NachoR: I see your point. I edited the last query in my answer, it should do what you want.

Comment: This is just what I wanted, now I can perform all the queries I need to update records. Hope this also helps someone else too :)